# Differences between Band and Act

Tags: word-choice, differences, terminology

When should I use 'band' and when 'act', particularly in the musical context?

Checking the Google Ngram service, I see that rock bands is more common than rock acts. Instead hip-hop acts is more common of hip-hop bands.

### Update

I add some more context from [Wikipedia](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21352/58492)

> Chicago house music acts from the early to mid-1980s found success on the US dance charts on various Chicago independent record labels that were more open to sign local house music artists. These same acts also experienced some success in the United Kingdom, garnering hits in that country. Due to this success, by the late 1980s, Chicago house music acts suddenly found themselves being offered major label deals.
>   [...]
>   UK acts such as The Beatmasters, Krush, [...] opened the doors to house music success on the UK charts.

Is there a reason why they do not say artists or bands for acts? Are they just synonymous? It does not seem to me here that "act" here is  used to mean a specific performance, like @Hot Licks suggest.

I am interested to everyday English or formal English as it might be used by Wikipedia and not some technical jargon used by music specialists (to answer @jsw29)

Comment: Perhaps I’m showing my age, but a “rock act” sounds like a reference to a performance while a “rock band” sounds like a group of people.

Comment: It might be expressing an [unconscious] opinion on the music: rock is music played by a band; hip-hop is not.

Comment: Partly, at least, it has to do with whether the group is purely playing music, or, in addition, providing some sort of visual display (beyond their mere presence).

Comment: An act could be one person; a group is not.

Comment: It needs to be noted that "act", in general context being discussed here, is often being used to mean a specific performance, vs referring to the group of performers.

Comment: @HotLicks (and @Lawrence), indeed, which makes it unclear what the question really is. The OP seems to assume that they are terms for things of the same general kind, and this is not how they are normally used in everyday English. Perhaps the question is about the use of *act* in some technical terminology used by the performers of such music, but if so, that needs to be explained, before anyone can even attempt to answer the question.

Comment: *Vaudeville act*, *circus act*, etc. Not *band*. The context needs to be narrowed.

Comment: @HotLicks:  If Band vs. Act is opinion based, why [Band vs. Group](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/21352/58492) is legit?

Comment: Ask FumbleFingers.

Comment: @antonio, the fact that some use of a word can be found in the Wikipedia in no way proves that it is not a part of a jargon. If you are really asking about the use of *act* in 'everyday English or formal English', then the answer is: it is not used in this way.

Comment: This is actually a very good question. My gut instinct tells me that a _band_ is a group of people who all visibly/audibly sing or play an instrument, which comes together to become music. An _act_ may be a band, but it may also be other constellations of people making music. A solo artist is an act, for instance. In the case of Chicago house music and much other electronic music, the thing that makes it sound weird to use the term bands is that they don’t _play music together_. It’s people sitting by a computer programming sounds and combining them, not playing instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context:

A *band* is a musical group.

An *act* is a person or group which gives a performance, not necessarily musical, often as one part of a longer public show. It can refer more to a specific *performance*, for example:

> After the ventriloquist, a talking animal *act* came on stage.

Or it can refer primarily to the *performers*:

> The Beatles were perhaps the greatest pop music *act* of all time.

- The talking animal performance was not musical: an act, but not a band.
- The Alan Parsons Project was studio only: a band, but not an act.
- The Beatles were both an act *and* a band.

#### References

https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/topic/live_music/act_3
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/topic/live_music/band_3